# Simple Method Output Process

Tags: c#

I have a basic class with this method including

```
public class Account
{
    //MEMBERS
    private int acctNo;
    protected double balance;
    public double deposit;


    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public Account() //member intitilization     
    {
        acctNo = 54534190;
        balance = 7500;
        deposit= 1500;



    }

    //PROPERTIES 
    public int AcctNo
    {
        get {return acctNo; }
        set {acctNo = value; }
    }
    public double Balance
    {
        get { return balance; }
        set { balance = value; }
    }

    public double Deposit
    {
        get {return deposit; }
        set   {deposit = value; }
    }
public virtual double getDeposit (double amount)
{
    double transactionAmt=0.00;
    if (amount>0)
    {
        balance+=amount;
       transactionAmt= amount;
    }
    return transactionAmt;
}
```

Now in my actual program I am trying to output this method. What would my writeline look like?

I tried to write this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CREATING ACCOUNT");
        Account myAcctDefault = new Account();

        DumpContents(myAcctDefault);
        Pause();
      }


    static void DumpContents(Account account)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(" output {0}", account.getDeposit());
    }
```

I am getting an error saying:

> no overload for method 'getDeposit' takes 0 arguments.

What am I doing wrong, am I trying to output this method incorrect?

Any help, insight or suggestions would be extremely helpful.

I am new to c# as I'm sure you can tell. What is the proper process to output a method in this context?

Comment: method getDeposit needs an argument of type double

Comment: First place your code Of Account Class , because how to definition of class is important also your argument definition.

Comment: @AliSarshogh thank you, I have updated with my full class so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am getting an error saying "no overload for method 'getDeposit' takes 0 arguments". What am I doing wrong

Exactly what it says. Here's your method call:

```
Console.WriteLine(" output {0}", account.getDeposit());
```

... and here's the method declaration:

```
public virtual double getDeposit (double amount)
```

Note how the method declares a parameter - but you're not providing an argument. Either you need to get rid of the parameter, or you need to add an argument to the method call. Or you need to change to using a different method - one which doesn't change the balance of the account. (It seems unlikely that you want to do that in this case.) Perhaps you should add a `Balance` property:

```
// Please note that this should probably be decimal - see below
public double Balance { get { return balance; } }
```

Then call it with:

```
Console.WriteLine(" output {0}", account.Balance);
```

Additionally:

- For financial quantities, it's generally better to use `decimal` than `double`. Read my articles on [decimal floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) and [binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) for more information.
- Your `getDeposit` method doesn't follow .NET naming conventions, where (at least public) methods are named in PascalCase, with a leading capital letter
- Your `getDeposit` method is oddly named as it isn't "getting" a deposit - it's *making* a deposit (and returning the balance)
- Your `getDeposit` method always returns the value passed into it, unless it's negative. That seems odd to me - if it's going to return anything, shouldn't it return the balance?
- Your `getDeposit` method silently ignores negative deposits. I'd expect this to throw an error, as trying to make a negative deposit indicates a programming error IMO.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm a beginner programer, so I'm getting use to all the terminology and naming conventions. Your explanation is extremely descriptive and helpful. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have updated my post with the full class I have so far. I do have the properties, and I fully agree that my "getDeposit" naming makes no sense. I was just trying to learn this inheritance project I am working on. Thanks again

Comment: @user2133925: Given that your properties just return and set variables, you should consider using automatically implemented properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: I gave it a read, but it seemed a little to complex for my basic knowledge. I bookmarked it and will see if I can grasp it the future. Thank you again for all your help. I'm still stuck on this error, but I think I'm going to approach it from a new angle and start over.

Comment: @user2133925: Well, blindly adding `{get;set;}` to your public/protected declarations is generally harmless and often helpful in the future, so maybe do it despite not understanding the purpose? Yeah, blind habits are probably a bad practice, but replacing your blind habit of not using `{get;set;}` with the blind habit of using `{get;set;}` is probably still a net win. A few things will mysteriosly work better (e.g., serialization).

Answer (score 6):

Your `getDeposit` method takes one argument that you are not passing to it. Depends what you want to achieve either pass a value to method:

```
static void DumpContents(Account account)
{
    double deposit = 1000;
    Console.WriteLine(" output {0}", account.getDeposit(deposit));
}
```

or remove this <strike>argument</strike>parameter from the method signature.

Comment: Quick note on terminology - the method has a *parameter*; a call to the method would provide an *argument*. So you'd remove the parameter from the method signature, for example... or change the calling code to provide an argument (where it's not currently doing so). It's a good idea for new developers to get this terminology ingrained nice and early, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

```
//You have to pass a double value into the method, because there is only one method    
//and wants a double paramater: 

//this is what you created: 
public double getDeposit(double amount) // <-
{
    double transactionAmt = 0.00;
    if (amount > 0)
    {
    balance += amount;
    transactionAmt = amount;
    }
    return transactionAmt;
}

//This how you should call it: 
static void DumpContents(Account account)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" output {0}", account.getDeposit(34.90)); //<- 
}
```

Comment: why does it just out "34" instead of doing what I coded in my method?

Comment: Because I passed 34, and since I edited with passing 34.90, the method will return 34.90.

Comment: If you call a method without parameter like this: 
Console.WriteLine(" output {0}", account.getDeposit()); 
 
you need to create a method without paramater, such as: 
public double getDeposit()

Comment: But the whole point of my class and method is so I can add the current balance method of 7500 to the deposit method of 1500 giving me an output of 9000. How would I get this to work?

Comment: First create a method without paramater:
public double getDeposit()
{
    return balance + deposit; 
}

And now calling it you will get 9000:
Console.WriteLine(" output {0}", account.getDeposit()); 

However, I made it just working, but could be improved.